# Why my SeekBar isn't updating?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have implemented an seekbar to my app which is a simple music player. But when I play the music (received from uri) it just doesn't update itself on run. But when I move it to some position it moves the song there. Any ideas how to solve this problem ?

My code:

```
public class MusicPlayer extends ThemableActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
MediaPlayer musicPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_player_layout);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String track = intent.getDataString();
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txt.setText(track);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    final Uri uri = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getData() : null;
    final SharedPreferences premiumSettings = getSharedPreferences("PREMIUM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final boolean isPremium = premiumSettings.getBoolean("isPremium", false);
    final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


    if (isPremium) {
        musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MusicPlayer.this, uri);
        seekBar.setMax(musicPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
        musicPlayer.start();
        final ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        if(!musicPlayer.isPlaying()){

            play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
        else{
            play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

        }
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                if(musicPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    musicPlayer.pause();
                    play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

                }
                else {
                    musicPlayer.seekTo(position);
                    musicPlayer.start();
                    play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

            }}
        });
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(musicPlayer!=null){
                    int mCurrentPosition = musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        ImageButton exit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_dialog);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (musicPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    musicPlayer.stop();
                }
                    musicPlayer.release();
                    musicPlayer = null;
                    finish();

            }
        });


    }
    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MusicPlayer.this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("You are not premium user. Please enter the promocode or buy the full version");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.holo_dark_action_info);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }}
public void onBackPressed () {
        if(musicPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            musicPlayer.stop();
        }
            musicPlayer = null;
        finish();
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    if (musicPlayer != null && b){
        musicPlayer.seekTo(i * 1000);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runnable does never run, in the snippet you posted. I would have expected either `mHandler.post(mRunnable);` or `mRunnable.run();`, outside the Runnable itself

Comment: I've put the mRunnable.run() after the Runnable definistion and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

create a simple thread say "progressSeekBarOnEverySecond"

```
progressSeekBarOnEverySecond=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(seekBar != null) 
            {
                seekBar.setProgress(musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                textviewCurrentVideoTime.setText((musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000)/60 +":"+(musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000)%60);   
            }

            if(musicPlayer.isPlaying()) 
            {
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }

        }
    };
```

and run the thread ..at the time you click play..or whatever logic you want to use

> textviewCurrentVideoTime is the textview ..at which i'm showing the current time of video..also note that once the thread is called ..it will automatically call itself in 1sec and the seekbar progress to currentposition of the video